# Mysql without installer is not working

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded MYSQL without installer suppourt in my windows 64 bit machine .
I have followed the guidelines mentioned in this website

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-install-archive.html**

i have installed it inside c: mysql directory .

As first step i navigated to c:\mysql\bin>mysqld , as shown in picture below . This started the Database

[image]

Then i opened another command Prompt Window and navigated to c:\mysql\bin> and typed show databases;

With this it it showing an Error in Command Prompt saying

[image]

Comment: You have to launch the mysql command line tool by typing `mysql` before you may type mysql commands.

Comment: First, cmd is not mysql console. Launch `mysql` command before executing any queries. Second, I believe this question is better suited for SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks a lot , the document hasn't mentioned this thing i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

There's two parts, your MySQL Server and your MySQL Client.

`mysqld` command launches the MySQL Server.

You have to launch the MySQL Client to interact with your Server, with command line tool by typing `mysql` before you may type mysql commands.

Answer (score 0):

From your second image enter mysql - then you're "in" mysql, and should do all your mysql operations there.  The second image is "just a command prompt", not in mysql, so windows itself doesn't recognize such commands.  Try a sql statement like 'SHOW STATUS' after entering the mysql application with `mysql`.